# Как создать шапку для сайта?

Tags: html, css

Есть рисунок шапки, надо конвертировать в html и css.

Comment: Вперёд, берёте и верстаете!

Comment: Звучит как приказ :)

Comment: А как звучит: "конвертировать в html и css"

Answer (score 7):

Автоматического "преобразования" не существует.
У Вас скорее всего PSD ну или один из форматов изображений. Процесс преобразования называется "верстка", а людей, которые занимаются этим процессом - "верстальщики". За умеренную плату можно найти человека на фрилансе или научиться самостоятельно.

Comment: А чего минус-то поставили?! Все ж правильно написал.

Comment: А я + поставлю) Очень подробно описал =)